# Create chart in Google Sheets to predict win/loss data over time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've been unable to find tips to apply to my scenario. I keep data on gambling wins and loses. I want to create a chart in Google Sheets to predict future win/loss data over time with dollars on the y-axis and time on the x-axis. I should point out my spreadsheet includes dates with no data (for a reason). I've included a [sample sheet][1]. My knowledge of spreadsheets is severely limited. I know just enough to get in trouble. I don't think the chart I created is working properly. Thanks in advance for any help, this is my second question on the forum.

Comment: Please clarify your actual problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find the references in [this resource](https://www.underdogchance.com/learn-to-bet/sports-betting-models/) a useful starting point.

Your choice of Google Sheets seems to be a sound one.

From the linked resource :

> Google spreadsheets are the simplest tool to build sports betting
> models for every sports bettor. They are free, user-friendly, and easy
> to learn programming languages. Most sports bettors understand the
> importance of analytical betting, but like the majority of the
> population in the world, they don’t enjoy mathematics, programming, or
> statistics. Most programming languages and algorithms are too complex
> for an average sports bettor.
>
> This is why Google Spreadsheet is so useful because it is the simplest
> one, but can bring good betting results.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks.